# How to download Ubuntu updates to a flash drive, and use it to update other PCs?

Tags: upgrade, usb, updates, offline

If:
(a)- your PC is a totally offline system

or:
(b)- you have multiple PCs with the same kind of hard and software configuration,

Is it possible to download the latest upgrades to a USB flash drive, and install them offline to the other PC/PCs?

If so, what are the procedures to retrieve the data from the net, onto the flash drive;

And what are the procedures to retrieve the data from the flash drive, onto the other computers, using Ubuntu/Lubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `apt-offline` package:

> Description: offline APT package manager
>
> apt-offline is an Offline APT Package Manager.
>
> apt-offline can fully update and upgrade an APT based distribution without
> connecting to the network, all of it transparent to APT.
>
> apt-offline can be used to generate a signature on a machine (with no network).
> This signature contains all download information required for the APT database
> system. This signature file can be used on another machine connected to the
> internet (which need not be a Debian box and can even be running windows) to
> download the updates.
> The downloaded data will contain all updates in a format understood by APT and
> this data can be used by apt-offline to update the non-networked machine.
>
> apt-offline can also fetch bug reports and make them available offline.

- Here's an [example of shell usage](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT). It's easy to learn.  From the same page, here is how to use it:

> Using apt-offline:
>
> You generate a signature on your Debian box at home and carry the signature file on a removable medium (Probably a USB Stick).(e.g. "apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.txt")
>
> Now you take the USB Stick (with the apt-offline.txt signature file) to the office machine which could be running any linux version, or as I mentioned above, even Windows.
>
> There, you could run apt-offline giving it the signature file. (e.g. "apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.txt")
>
> apt-offline would generate you an archive file or a folder with all the data.
>
> That data can be copied on a removable media. The removable media can be attached back to the disconnected Debian box at home and installed. (e.g. "apt-offline install /tmp/apt-offline.zip")

- Here's [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt-offline.8.html)

...or you can make things SUPER-easy with the `apt-offline-gui` package.

> This package contains the graphical user interface to apt-offline.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the explanation,
Do I need to generate a signature for each system, or can I use 1 signature to update all other PCs?

Comment: If you're *really* sure that each machine's configuration is identical, you should be able to use the same signature. If it turns out that their configuration is not identical, that has the potential to cause problems.

Comment: Considering that I've plugged in Ubuntu drives from one pc, into another, and it worked fine, I think it'll be ok. They were Legacy OS installs though.
I know with UEFI, a dd drive clone doesn't work in different hardware.
But yes, all the units are Atomic Pis.
I actually found a more modern Ubuntu alternate installation, which I could enable a persistent partition. I will see if this one is good enough for my purposes, as I'm having trouble loading apt-offline on the offline pc.