# How to update packages and apply hardening rules on servers without internet connection?

Tags: 18.04, offline

I have several new Ubuntu 18.04 servers that were scanned for compliance and vulnerabilities. The scan results show that I need to update certain packages and apply hardening rules. These servers are interconnected, but will not have internet connection.

I did some research and came across CIS Compliance Tools from Canonical. Is it possible to download this application and install the package (complete with its dependencies) on each of the servers, then run it to apply the hardening rules? I believe I have to pay for the support services in order for me to download the package.

For updating the packages, any suggestions on how to do this?

I would appreciate any help and inputs.

Comment: AskUbuntu is run by volunteers and enthusiasts. It's not for Canonical customer service or sales inquiries. We don't answer questions about commercial Canonical products.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download Ubuntu updates to a flash drive, and use it to update other PCs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261501/how-to-download-ubuntu-updates-to-a-flash-drive-and-use-it-to-update-other-pcs)

Comment: As for updating the packages, it seems apt-offline is the solution that I can use.

But how about server hardening? Any ideas? @user535733

Comment: Ubuntu Server is already designed to be safe out-of-the-box. Your Question claims that you already have some list of hardening suggestions. Implement them, or do not. It's up to you.